# Spring ApplicationContext with multiple context xml files from different projects in an application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have two different projects in my application: data, web
I want to Auto wire a dao defined in my data in the web application layer.
So I created a master applicationContext.xml file in web and imported the entire Spring bean files like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <import resource="data/src/main/resources/spring/applicationContext-data.xml"/>
        <import resource="applicationContext.xml"/>

</beans>
```

```java
@Configuration("file:**/Master-Module.xml")
public class MyService{
    @Autowired
    public  IMyDAO myDao;
    Practice practice1 = myDao.findById("3900");
```

The interface IMyDAO is defined in applicationContext-data.xml

When I deploy the application to Websphere and run it I get a NULL pointer exception.

Id is present in database.
It builds successfully in Maven when run as independent projects.

Below is the error I get:

```
2/28/15 12:45:13:902 EST] 0000009d ServletWrappe I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [webapp-7_0-SNAPSHOT_war] [/web] [/WEB-INF/views/common/footer.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[2/28/15 12:45:13:762 EST] 0000009d SystemErr     R java.lang.NullPointerException
[2/28/15 12:45:13:762 EST] 0000009d SystemErr     R     at cic.web.service.MyPracticeService.retrievPracticeDetails(MyPracticeService.java:51)
[2/28/15 12:45:13:762 EST] 0000009d SystemErr     R     at cic.web.controllers.MyPracticeController.practicesList(MyPracticeController.java:42)
[2/28/15 12:45:13:762 EST] 0000009d SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[2/28/15 12:45:13:762 EST] 0000009d SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
[2/28/15 12:45:13:762 EST] 0000009d SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
[2/28/15 12:45:13:762 EST] 0000009d SystemErr     R     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)​
```

Answer (score 1):

You can load multiple spring contexts declaring then in `web.xml`

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
   <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>
</listener>
```